# How do I get the current user for my created_by field in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, httprequest

I'm trying to pull the session user into my model's save() method.  [The docs for HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and all the examples I've found assume you already have the object instanciated, but I can't seem to find a method that will do the instanciation.

I'm thinking I should be using `HttpRequest.user` , but I don't know how to generate the instance in my model so I can actually do it.

Here's my save() override.  It generates `type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'user'`, but considering this is a class and not an object reference that isn't really surprising.:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    if not hasattr(self, 'id'):
        self.date_created = timezone.now()
        self.created_by = HttpRequest.user

    self.last_updated_date = timezone.now()
    self.last_updated_by = HttpRequest.user

    super(Caregiver, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

views.py added for more info

```
class CaregiverCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'single_form_generic.html'
    model = Caregiver
    form_class = CaregiverCreateForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig around a little, but I did end up finding an answer for you future googlers:

The [class based view docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) actually have a relevant example.  Since the view already has access to the request and the form and model are tied, you really only need to inject it in the view submission by overriding the form_valid method there.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    form.instance.last_updated_by = self.request.user
    return super(CaregiverCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2):

[django-cuser](https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-cuser) can do this easily. This library adds middleware that can be called in a view, model method, etc to get the current user. If you are ok with the user being assigned at the model's save method, then you just need to call the middleware to inspect the session as below.

Once set up, it can be called like this:

```
from cuser.middleware import CuserMiddleware

class YourModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_by = CuserMiddleware.get_user()
        super(YourModel,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `save()` explicitly, you could pass the user instance directly to the method:

```
def save(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    # use the user
```

Then when you call it in views.py, do:

```
instance.save(request.user)
```

Comment: I'm using class based views.  How would I added that?  I added views.py in my question for clarity.

Comment: While I didn't use this method I did +1 it because it lead me to the answer.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found your answer. I took at second look and sounds like what you trying to do can totally be achieved by overriding `form_valid` method on class based views.

Comment: That's what I ended up using.  I added the answer below for googlers from the future :)

Comment: Also, even your case is simple enough, I don't suggest overriding default `save` method, because django has a whole process setup when saving an instance, so it's easily messed up. It's better to use signal `pre_save` to achieve this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save. It even has the parameter `update_fields` and stuff so you don't need to do `if not hasattr(self, 'id')`.